# Setting up Oracle Datasource using Railo

Tags: oracle, datasource, railo

I am trying to set an Oracle datasource in Railo and I am receiving the following error: no ocijdbc10 in java.library.path. the following is what I am using:

Oracle 11
Windows Server 2008

I can successfully use an oracle datasource using the thin client driver type but when I switch it over to oci, I receive the no ocijdbc10 in java.library.path. Which is confusing since I am using Oracle 11.

Thanks